# Active content for sidebar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing a rails app that I intend to use active content to at least fill in a side-bar. Specifically, it's meant to display recent messages sent by users of the app.

Right now, I'm just trying to get the sidebar to display the recent messages regardless of which controller is handling the page.

views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <%= render 'layouts/head' %>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/nav' %>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <%= render 'shared/sidebar_users' %>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <%= bootstrap_flash %>
          <%= yield %>
        </div>

        <%= render 'shared/sidebar_messages' %>
      </div><!--/row-->

      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <%= render 'layouts/debug' %>
  </body>
</html>
```

views/shared/_sidebar_messages.html.erb

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="well sidebar-nav">
    <h3>Recent Posts</h3>

    <%= render partial: "messages/messages", locals: { display_actions: false } %>
  </div><!--/.well -->
</div><!--/span-->
```

views/messages/_messages.html.erb

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Creator</th>
      <th>Content</th>
      <% if @display_actions %>
        <th colspan="3">Actions</th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @messages.each do |message| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= message.creator.full_name %></td>
        <td><%= message.content %></td>
        <% if display_actions %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', message, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note the code breaks at this line, stating that @messages is nil and thus doesn't have an each method.

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
```

Comment: Let us know if one of the answers below was useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what is happening here is that @messages is not defined, when you work with partials you need to pass the variables manually to it. You can't just define the `@messages` instance variable in your messages controller and expect to work everywhere.

If your messages always have the same logic regardless the controller then you can define it in your application controller so it will be available across your view actions:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :set_messages

  private
  def set_var
    @messages = #Logic here for get the messages
  end
end
```

Then in any view action you want to render the sidebar you need to pass the variable:

```
<%= render 'shared/sidebar_messages', messages: @messages %> #Note that you do not need to use locals anymore in rails 4
```

and of course in your sidebar pass the `messages` to the `_messages.html.erb`

Another approach is to create a helper and use it in your partial instead of `@messages` variable:

in your application helper
def get_messages_for_sidebar
  #Here you can get return the messages as you wish.
end

Then in your `_messages.html.erb` partial call your helper:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Creator</th>
      <th>Content</th>
      <% if display_actions %>
        <th colspan="3">Actions</th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% get_recent_messages.each do |message| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= message.creator.full_name %></td>
        <td><%= message.content %></td>
        <% if display_actions %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', message, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Another approach is to use a Scope, a Scope in your message.rb model.

in your `message.rb`

```
scope :get_recent, -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(10) } #get the last 10 most recent
```

And then you can just call `Message.get_recent` in your partial.

Comment: The AJAX part, That's another topic, please create another question and paste the link here, I will answer you.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Helper method to get Recent Messages and call that in `views/messages/_messages.html.erb`

In your `application_helper` add a method which return Recent Messages e.g

```
def get_recent_messages
    #What ever the logic is to get recent messages i-e Message.order('created_at desc').limit(10)
 end
```

Then in your Partial

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Creator</th>
      <th>Content</th>
      <% if display_actions %>
        <th colspan="3">Actions</th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% (@messages || get_recent_messages).each do |message| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= message.creator.full_name %></td>
        <td><%= message.content %></td>
        <% if display_actions %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', message, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Secondly You can create a named `scope` in `message.rb` to get recent messages and then call that in your partial like `Message.recent`